# Javascript to change opacity in everything BUT hovered image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

http://vanhoesenarchitecture.com/completed-works/

I've searched and found a few options but none have worked. Also, in my instance, they are not siblings, so I am struggling to get this to work. Here's the code I'm using:

```
(function($){
  jQuery('img').hover(function() {
    jQuery('img').not(this).addClass('hovered');
    console.log("HOVERED");
  }, function() {
    jQuery('img').removeClass('hovered');
    console.log("NOT HOVERED");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

CSS:

`.hovered {opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why you put `removeClass` directly in the `callback`?

Comment: I thought it might help. Even with it removed it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your logic looks fine, but we need to see the accompanying HTML and CSS in order to help you. Please edit the question to include them

Comment: I should also add that it won't even show up in the console when hovered/not hovered.

Comment: It's a WordPress site, so how much of the code should I post?

Comment: Just the relevant HTML output, not any of the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/*(function($) {
  jQuery('img').hover(
    function() {
      jQuery('img').not(this).addClass('hovered');
      console.log("HOVERED");
    },
    function() {
      jQuery('img').removeClass('hovered');
      console.log("NOT HOVERED");
    });
})(jQuery);

*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').hover(
    function() {
      jQuery('img').not(this).addClass('hovered');
      console.log("HOVERED");
    },
    function() {
      jQuery('img').removeClass('hovered');
      console.log("NOT HOVERED");
    }
  );
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img.hovered {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src='http://vanhoesenarchitecture.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/lone-pine-lodge-17.jpg'>

<img src='http://vanhoesenarchitecture.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/lone-pine-lodge-17.jpg'>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong here? How do you want it to function?

Comment: Yea, that's not working like that on the page: http://vanhoesenarchitecture.com/completed-works/

Comment: Please open console for your page and paste the above javascript there. Can you confirm if its working?

Comment: Very strange. When I plug in the js nothing. but when i also add the jquery <script> into the console it works great. When i add the jquery.min.js into the actual site I get

 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

Comment: Argh! That just made me figure it out. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

(function($){

jQuery('img').mouseover(function() {

```
jQuery(this).addClass('hovered');

console.log("HOVERED");
```

})

jQuery('img').mouseleave(function() {

```
jQuery(this).removeClass('hovered');

console.log("HOVERED Leave");
```

})

})
(jQuery);